# resize and save transparent PNG file in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, png, transparency, matlab-figure

I have an transparent png file(colored image not black and white).I want to resize this png file and save that with transparent background.but i cant save that with transparent background.file saved with dark background.

```
     [im,map]=imread('image.png');
     im=ind2rgb(im,map);
     im2=imresize(im,[200,200]);
     imwrite(im2,'image2.png');
```

in above code image2.png saved with black background and not transparent

Comment: Try `imwrite(im2,map,'image2.png');` and removing the `ind2rgb` call

Comment: thanks for reply but not work;

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly you have to read the transparency (alpha) value of the Image. Then you have to scale that value as well. Then you can write the Image with the alpha value.

```
[im, map, alpha] = imread('image.png');

im2=imresize(im,[200,200]);
resizedAlpha = imresize(alpha,[200, 200]);

imwrite(im2, 'image2.png', 'Alpha', resizedAlpha);
```

Comment: I tested it and it works. Anyway, this code is almost the same as the one you linked as answer except different variable names.